# How do restrict checkBoxes to select after some condition

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I am using `ngModel` in Angular 5 and here is `Html`

```
 <span *ngFor="let id of Ids">
  <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="strManyModel[id]"   (change)="setValue($event)" [value]="id">
 </span>
```

And here is `typeScript`

```
setValue(e){
   if(selectedChkBox > 5){
    this.strManyModel[e.target.value] = false;// if check box more than 5 selected , unselect this one
  }
}
```

I want to restrict check boxes to selected once 5 check boxes is being selected. At first click once 5 is selected , ia m able to restrict to checkbox to select , but at same time if it is again select it is going to select. Want to restrict check boxes to check once 5 is checked. At a time at max 5 check boxes to select out of many. One can select other one only if he uncheck any older one which was selected in case 5 is selected.

Comment: Sorry but it is really hard to understand your question. Do you want to limit the input list to a maximum of 5 checked checkbox?

Comment: @ForestG yes see the edit

Answer (score 3):

Create additional class property like:

```
public maxElementCheckbox = 5;
```

Then use a function:

```
public disableCheckbox(): boolean {
  return Ids.length >= this.maxElementCheckbox;
}
```

Template is:

```
<input class="checkbox" [disabled]="disableCheckbox()" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="strManyModel[id]" (change)="setValue($event, i)" [value]="id">
```

Comment: if 5 check boxes have selected and some body want to uncheck some older one and want to select some other how does he will able to do this , if all check boxes is being disabled

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to disable other checkboxes when 5 are chosen and keep the unchecked disabled until checked boxes are less than 5...

What you could do, have objects in your array, witch a `checked` property to keep track on the checked state, as well as introduce a new boolean and a "counter" to keep track of how many checkboxes are checked. Disable the checkboxes that are not checked and when the maximum of 5 checkboxes have been chosen:

```
<div *ngFor="let chk of checkBox; let i = index">
  <input [(ngModel)]="chk.checked" 
         type="checkbox" 
         [disabled]="!chk.checked && maxNo" 
         (change)="onChange($event.target.checked)">{{chk.name}}
</div>
```

Where the array would consist of objects with `name` and `checked` property. Then your change event would increment/decrement based on checked checkboxes and switch the boolean flag `maxNo`:

```
onChange(isChecked: boolean) {
  isChecked ? this.amt++ : this.amt--;
  this.maxNo = this.amt === 5 ? true : false;
}
```

Here's a

### [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8ghcjz?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: A smart work-around \m/ This exactly does what is needed:) This should be the selected answer!

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution might be:

```
 <span *ngFor="let id of Ids; index as i">
  <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="strManyModel[id]"   (change)="setValue($event, i)" [value]="id">
 </span>

 setValue(e, index){
         if(Ids.length >= 5){
          strManyModel[index] = false;
        }
     }
```

Comment: This isn't a bad idea, not worth a downvote or anything, but the UX will be sub-par